# Fix Caption column which is dependent on other Flags?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to populate caption column depending on other flags and I am using case statement to achieve this. Unfortunately I am encountering problem with result. Caption should be same for each primary irrespective of Detail Flag.

Code:

```sql
SELECT Primary_Key, Detail_Flag, Flag_A, Flag_B,
  CASE WHEN Detail_Flag=0 THEN
    CASE WHEN Flag_A=1 AND Flag_B=1 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END 
  END AS IsCommercialFlag,

  CASE WHEN Flag_A=1 AND Flag_B=1 THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No'
  END
  AS IsCommercialFlagCaption

FROM TableFlags 
WHERE Primary_Key IN (123, 456)
ORDER BY Primary_Key, Detail_Flag
```

Actual Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: the images are not seen pls do not upload images

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Your Flag A and Flag B is null. So you get 'No'. If you want 'Yes' use Isnull([Flag a],1) and Isnull([Flag B],1)

Comment: I am trying to populate same caption value for same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need NULL handling. Considering you are currently using ORACLE as your DBMS product, You may try below query -

```
SELECT 
 Primary_Key,
 Detail_Flag, 
 Flag_A, 
 Flag_B,
  CASE WHEN Detail_Flag=0 THEN
    CASE WHEN NVL(Flag_A, 1) = 1 AND NVL(Flag_B, 1) = 1 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END 
  END AS IsCommercialFlag,    
  CASE WHEN NVL(Flag_A, 1) = 1 AND NVL(Flag_B, 1) = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No'
  END
  AS IsCommercialFlagCaption

FROM TableFlags 
WHERE Primary_Key IN (123, 456)
ORDER BY Primary_Key, Detail_Flag
```

If you are using MySQL, just replace `NVL` with `IFNULL`, For SQL SERVER user ISNULL.

Comment: I am not just trying to handle null when Flags are NULL. I just want same caption for each primary key.

Comment: Ok, What is the criteria to choose the Caption for each Primary_Key.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions:

```
SELECT Primary_Key, Detail_Flag, Flag_A, Flag_B,
       (CASE WHEN Detail_Flag = 0 AND Flag_A = 1 AND Flag_B = 1
             THEN 1
             WHEN Detail_Flag = 0
             THEN 0 
        END) AS IsCommercialFlag,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(Flag_A) OVER (PARTITION BY Primary_Key) = 1 AND
                  MAX(Flag_B) OVER (PARTITION BY Primary_Key) = 1
             THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
        END) AS IsCommercialFlagCaption
FROM TableFlags 
WHERE Primary_Key IN (123, 456)
ORDER BY Primary_Key, Detail_Flag;
```

You also seem to have no understanding of what "primary key" means in a database.  It is *unique* meaning that the values are not repeated.  I strongly advise you to not use such a name for a column that does have repeated values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I was looking out.

SELECT Primary_Key, Detail_Flag, Flag_A, Flag_B,
  CASE WHEN Detail_Flag=0 THEN
    CASE WHEN Flag_A=1 AND Flag_B=1 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END 
  END AS IsCommercialFlag,

CASE WHEN SUM(Flag_A) over (Order by PrimaryKey) = 1 AND 
       SUM(Flag_B)over (Order by PrimaryKey) = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No'
  END
  AS IsCommercialFlagCaption

FROM TableFlags 
WHERE Primary_Key IN (123, 456)
ORDER BY Primary_Key, Detail_Flag